# Importing a Function in Python: ImportError "moduleX has no attribute Y"

Tags: python, importerror

I'm attempting to import a function defined in another file into the one I am working in.

The function I'm trying to import is in a file called ParallelEqns.py and looks like:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import sympy as sym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

def ParDeriv(x,p):
    derivative = []
    for k in range(nS):
        test = x[(k-1)%nS]*(x[(k+1)%nS] - x[(k-2)%nS]) - x[(k)%nS] + p
        if k == 0:
            derivative = test
        else:
            derivative = np.vstack([derivative, test])
    return derivative
```

The file I'm working in looks like:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import sympy as sym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

from ParallelEqns import ParDeriv
```

That gives me an error of "cannot import name 'ParDeriv'"

If I change the file to:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import sympy as sym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

import ParallelEqns

ParDeriv = ParallelEqns.ParDeriv
```

I get an error that says "module 'ParallelEqns' has no attribute 'ParDeriv'"

I've checked that both files are in the same directory. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Edit: I've answered my own question by closing everything down and restarting python. It looks like I needed to restart python after creating the ParallelEqns.py file for it to correctly import

Comment: This sounds like something you might get from a circular import error. What did you call the file that's trying to import `ParallelEqns`? Did you call it the same thing as one of the other modules you're trying to use - for example, something like `numpy.py`? Show us the complete stack trace of the error.

Comment: The file trying to import ParallelEqns is called "MaskedVegas.py"

Looks like I figured it out. Just needed to restart python

Comment: If all the imported libraries where installed, I think you just need to add `__init__.py` inside your working directory if not present.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I just needed to restart python as I had created the file that I was trying to import after starting up python. Once I did that it worked out